# Kubuntu cannot shut down properly

Tags: ubuntu, boot, kubuntu

I have just installed Kubuntu 22.04 on my Acer laptop. Everything seemed ok at first until I restarted or shut down my machine, it always stops at the motherboard logo, if I don't force restart it, it will just stuck like that until the battery is drained out.

Note that this symptom also appeared when I ran the installation of Kubuntu. When the installation was finished, it prompted me to "remove the installation medium, then press Enter", I did what it said and the symptom appeared. The only difference is that it just showed a blinking cursor at the top left of the screen. (I thought this was a small problem with first-time boot, so I didn't mind about that, and I just force restarted it.)

How to fix that? What should I do?

**Update:** I decided to reinstall this OS, this time, it didn't even boot up (after choosing Kubuntu in Grub menu, it froze with the blinking cursor). I also set the BIOS password and turned off secure boot, but nothing changed.

Comment: If there is no data or personalization worth saving, I'd just try reinstalling, which is fairly quick.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have just reinstalled Kubuntu but that doesn't solve. My machine is being stopped at the blinking cursor after removing the installation USB.

Comment: On one Acer, I had to set a BIOS password to access features needed to install another OS. Has that been done? Also, plain Ubuntu, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ has a good installer that's been quite successful for my needs.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik please see my update in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try installing nvidia drivers on your machine and see how it goes. In your terminal type in:

```
sudo /usr/bin/software-properties-qt
```

Now, reach to additional drivers section and check if there are any drivers that you have to install. If there are any, install the proper one (or the suggested one) and then restart your machine. See if this works.
In case there are no additional drivers available, then install nvidia from apt. Type in:

```
apt search nvidia-driver
```

Now, select one of them like `nvidia-driver-550`, install it and restart your machine. I suggest you to install the latest driver that's available. Now, if you head over to additional drivers, your going to see nvidia.

Comment: In additional drivers tab, it says: "no additional drivers available".

Comment: I will edit my answer then.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help!